# The Last Remained Number (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, game-theory

There is an array with N integer (N < 5x10^5) and there are two players(A and B) who are deleting the elements of this array sequentially. A is trying to make the last remained number bigger and B is trying to make smaller.

*Both players can delete **only** the first element or the last element. 
*A starts deleting first.

Let's say; A = [3,100,4,50]

-A will delete 50 because if A deletes 3 then B can delete 100 which is not the thing that A wants.

---

I have solved the problem by using dynamic programming but the problem is memory. I used a 2D integer array for memoization and when I receive an array with let's say 10^5 size, it consumes tons of memory (for this case 10^5x10^5x2 = 2x10^10 byte which is 18.6 gigabyte.) but I want to solve this problem with 512 mb memory at most. My question is "what would be the more space efficient way to solve this problem?".

Comment: A side note: reducing memory consumption from O(N^2) to O(N) most probably won't help as long as the time is still O(N^2). For N=1,000,000, the square is 10^{12}, so the solution will likely take a few hours to solve a single instance of the problem.

Comment: @Gassa I don't have a problem about time complexity. My concern is space complexity for now.

Comment: @Gassa But I will need to consider it later. Do you have a suggestion to tackle time complexity problem?

Comment: I'd start with the following question. Suppose there are `n` elements, `A[1], ..., A[n]`, player A wants the number `A[i]` to remain the last, player B wants to prevent it, and they both know the target index `i`. For which `i` player B can stop them and for which they can't?

Comment: The next question would be as follows. Suppose `n = 100`, the numbers `A[33]` and `A[66]` are large and all others are small. Will player A manage to get one of these large numbers as the last one remaining?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I don't think that you need dynamic programming here. The answer will always be the element in the middle, and in case if **N** is even, the answer is the maximum among the two middle elements. Here is the proof:

Suppose you are the player **A**, and you want the remaining element to be greater than the middle one. If the element is in the right half of the array, you will surely start taking elements from the start of the array (keeping the element you wish for as long as possible). Now think how will player **B** react, why would he help you achieve your goal?! Of course player **B** will start taking elements from the end of the array to get rid of the big element you are wishing for.

Same thing happens if you are player **B**, and you are trying to keep an element that is smaller than the middle one, player **A** will start taking elements from the other side to remove the small element that you are wishing for.

In case if both the big and small elements are at the same side of the array, both players can calculate whether or not they can have the element they are wishing for. If one of them can't get the element he wants, he will push the other player toward keeping the middle element for sure by always removing the element at the other side.

The only special case is if **N** is even, in this case the final step will be done by player **A**, and the array will have **2** elements left (which are the two elements at the middle). In this case surely player **A** will remove the smaller element and keep the bigger one.

Comment: I know what is your question, and Peter has already answered it. I just thought you might be interested in an O(1) solution that's all ;)

Comment: I have been thinking about this problem for 2 days, yet I couldn't realize this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @Said. Could you recommend a resource for us to learn Game Theory?

Comment: This pdf was once recommended to me by a great coach, hope it's as helpful to you as it was to me: 

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/comb.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you compute the best score for all length k arrays (k will start at 1 and gradually increase) and with both choices of first player.

You can compute the best score for all length k+1 arrays just from the length k arrays (by considering removing the first or last element and picking the best).

Therefore you can do this with O(N) memory by keeping just two copies of this array (k and k+1) and discarding all smaller lengths.

In other words, if you store the results in a 2d array of size [2][N], you can store the result for length k arrays in position k%2 (which will either be 0 or 1).

Comment: Nice answer. I think it's worth noting that this method is called rolling table technique.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me very much of alpha-beta pruning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning). A/B-pruning is applicable to situations where you have a two player competitive game *and* you can assign a score to each move of the game, for instance, chess or checkers but this should work equally well.

The problem boils down to a tree search over possible game states and scores, in this case differential scores between the players, for each state. A/B-pruning allows the search space to be reduced, entire sub-trees to be cut off, based on the expected score for the *opposing* player. The idea is that sub-trees that lead to a score for the opposing player that is higher than your own expected score do not need to be taken into account.